# Parsing stdout text to map in ansible

Tags: ansible, terraform, packer

So,
I got a manifest file that packer produces.

I would like to parse the availability zone and the AMI ID out of it into
a map so I would later update my terraform variables with the matching zones and AMIS.

This is the file:

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "name": "amazon-ebs",
      "builder_type": "amazon-ebs",
      "build_time": 1545650590,
      "files": null,
      "artifact_id": "us-east-1:ami-0caa33152d1160000",
      "packer_run_uuid": "ba1f3c4c-9da1-60ed-e45e-1dc374bc148b"
    }
  ],
  "last_run_uuid": "ba1f3c4c-9da1-60ed-e45e-1dc374bc148b"
}
```

grep the relevant line with regex and cleaning it up was a piece of cake:

`grep -E "ami-\w" manifest.json | tr -d "[:space:],\"" | tr ":" "," | sed 's/artifact_id,//g`

(output: **us-east-1,ami-0caa33152d1160000**)

however, I couldn't find how do I register the output to a map and access it later with loop and conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the variable is in the file packer-manifest.txt you might want to use *json_query*.

```
vars_files:
  - packer-manifest.txt
tasks:
  - set_fact:
      ami_id: "{{ builds | json_query('[].artifact_id') }}"
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ ami_id[0].split(':')[1] }}"
```

Result is:

> ```
>    "msg": "ami-0caa33152d1160000"
> ```

Comment: This is great to avoid using bash to parse the text, thanks a lot
now to the other task of actually turning it to a key:value map

Comment: Ok... I've changed it a bit and found my solution
`msg: "{{ ami_id[0].split(':')[1] }}"`

Answer (score 0):

You should parse json files with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and rewrite it to a json file that you can pass to terraform with the `-var-file` argument, [see](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-files).

Sidenote: a better strategy then passing state from Packer to Terraform is to keep the state in AWS. By setting some tags on the resulting AMI of a Packer build and then using `data.aws_ami_id` to find the latest version.

Comment: Saving state in a backend will v2.0 ;-)

Comment: You don't need to save state anywhere to use the AWS data sources, they query the AWS API directly. Also this answer would be improved by an example of how to use the `aws_ami` data source along with tagging/naming schemes in Packer to hand off between Packer and Terraform (which is a much better approach than given by the other answer).

Comment: The point of my note is that the state is already in AWS, you just need to make it useful. And certainly there is a state. The AMI's and tags are the state.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it this way. I'd leave packer alone at this point, you can easily use data resources within Terraform to find out ami IDs, see the example here:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html